# Javascript code is right but not work in Microsoft Visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, switch-statement

simple coding in javascript using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 in a VM.

The user I am helping is using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 in a VM. Simple development using javascript and html.

The code is right - I have taken the code, created a project in a localized version of Visual Studio Community 2019 and it works. Another user has the same code inside a separate VM identical to my user and it works.

The code in question is a switch statement. The buttons in the table when pressed calls the switch statement but none of the cases are met. We know this because we put an alert at the switch and the alert popped up, but when we put alerts in the case statement, it didn't appear (not to mention the buttons didn't work). Again,full functionality using the same code (all inside index.cshtml) on two other versions.

We also know the refresh function is working - so the script there is no question the script code is being read.

So we know this code works in two separate versions of Microsoft Visual studio, one inside a VM like my user and one in a standalone local version.

We've tried F12 and we get some statement about a carat that apparently is a recurring problems. Since its an enterprise version inside a VM I am reluctant to ask the user to do anything radical like devenv /resetuserdata

So this really isn't a coding issue, but I'm at a loss to troubleshoot because of a success of building the projects in other Visual Studio installations. Let me add- this isn't copying a solution from one environment to the other, its building individual projects and using the same code.

```
<script>
function RefreshPage() {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
    function ClearFields(field) {
        switch (field) {
            case 'I':
                $("#txtItemNumber").val("");
                break;
            case 'A':
                $("#txtItemNumber, #txtCategoryNumber").val("");
                break;
            case 'C':
                $("#txtCategoryNumber").val("");
                break;
        }
    }
</script>

 <td>
            <input placeholder="ItemNumber" type="text" id="txtItemNumber"
                   style="font-size:large;text-align: center; height: 44px;" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
            <div>
                <button onclick="RefreshPage(); return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Refresh</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <div>
                <button onclick="ClearFields('I'); return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-clear"></span>Clear</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <div>
                <button onclick="ClearFields('A'); return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-clear"></span>ClearAll</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label style="font-size:large;">
                Enter Category Number:&nbsp;
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input placeholder="Category Number" type="text" id="txtCategoryNumber"
                   style="font-size:large; text-align: center; height: 44px;" />
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 22px;">
            <div>
                <button onclick="ClearFields('C'); return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon=clear"></span> Clear</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some internet sluething I focused on the Jquery not working.

In this case I was able to solve the problem by adding a new script statement that pointed to

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then we found the offending code. Even though it was sourcing jquery-3.2.1.min.js, there was another reference in the _layoutPage.cshtml file that included this line

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")"></script>
```

which was overriding. This piece of code resulted in jQuery not working and would not have worked until we addressed the multiple jQuery.xxx.js files being referenced throughout the project.